# Equivalence of window.onbeforeunload in AngularJS for routes

Tags: angularjs

Regular JavaScript has window.onbeforeunload. How do I emulate the same in AngularJS with HTML5 routes?

There is $beforeRouteChange, but it doesn't allow you to cancel the event as far as I can tell.

To clarify: window.onbeforeunload would work for navigating away from the page, but not for intra page navigation, e.g. going from one controller to another just through the HTML5 history API.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

There is a `$locationChangeStart` event which can be canceled.

Since it hasn't been documented yet, here is the unit test describing how it affects the `$route` service.
https://github.com/angular/angular.js/blob/v1.0.1/test/ng/routeSpec.js#L63

This doesn't provide a confirmation for the user like `window.onbeforeunload` does.  You need to bring your own dialog service and restart the location change process to get the same effect (or you could just use the synchronous `$window.confirm`).

Comment: @Freewind there is a check-in may 1, 2013 to make it work for back button: https://github.com/angular/angular.js/commit/dc9a580617a838b63cbf5feae362b6f9cf5ed986

Answer (score 21):

Add this :

```
$scope.$on('$destroy', function() {
   window.onbeforeunload = undefined;
});
$scope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function(event, next, current) {
   if(!confirm("Are you sure you want to leave this page?")) {
      event.preventDefault();
   }
});
```

Comment: For angular-ui-router `$stateChangeStart` should use. And it does not handle page refresh as it is handled in case of `window.onbeforeunload`

Comment: I had to listen for `$stateChangeStart` on `$rootScope` instead of `$scope` for this to work for me.  Note that if you do this you will need to manually unregister this event listener when your current scope is destroyed (`$scope.$on('$destroy, ...)`).

Answer (score 5):

If you are using angular-ui-router you need to use `$stateChangeStart` instead of `$locationChangeStart`.

Comment: Totally true ! Using `$locationChangeStart` with angular-ui-router is called when the controller is "started" and not when the user leaves a page.

Answer (score 0):

When using **UI-Router version 1.0.0+**, use `$transitions.onStart` instead of `$stateChangeStart`. See the [transition hooks](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks) documentation.

The `$stateChange*` events are deprecated as of version 1.0.0 ([source](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/ng1/migrate-to-1_0#state-change-events)):

> All state events, (i.e. `$stateChange*` and friends) are now deprecated
>   and disabled by default. Instead of listening for events, use the
>   Transition Hook API.

Example code to abort a transition ([source](https://ui-router.github.io/guide/transitionhooks#aborting-a-transition)):

```
$transitions.onStart({}, function(transition) {
  if (transition.to().name === 'unreachable') {
    return false;
  }
}
```